# Forwarding refs through multiple components

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui, styled-components, react-ref

I'm using Material-UI and styled-components for an app, and I'm trying to pass a ref down to the root `<button>` node created by MUI. MUI has a `buttonRef` prop for accessing it, so that's simple, however I'm using styled-components to style MUI's Button component like so:

```
const NavButtonMain = styled(Button)`
    ...
`
```

I'm also already relying pretty heavily on dynamic CSS in that button's styling , which is why I can't just use a regular CSS style sheet and access MUI's Button directly, like:

```
<Button buttonRef={ref} className={plain-old-css}/>
```

Styled-components has an innerRef prop...

```
<NavButtonMain innerRef={ref}/>
```

..but I don't know how to get it from there down one more level into the Button. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply pass the prop as `buttonRef` onto `NavButtonMain`, access and use it in `Button` Component like

```
<NavButtonMain buttonRef={ref}/>

<Button buttonRef={this.props.buttonRef} className={plain-old-css}/>
```

Comment: Thanks, but passing a ref through a prop like that makes React crash. I think I've managed to get it partly working by using React.forwardRef but I'm not entirely sure how yet. I'll post the code if I figure it all out.

Comment: @MatthewMasurka did you ever figure it out? I also need to forward the ref from a Component to another Component/PureComponent and i can't use functional stateless components on this one...

Answer (score 0):

In case somebody is searching for the soluition recently - latest docs explain that material-ui forwards the ref attribute under the hood so this is absolutely enough:

```
const myRef = useRef();
...
return <Button ref={ref} {...props} />
```